# accessing my gmail inbox via php code

Tags: php, email, gmail, pop3

how i can access my gmail account through my php code? I need to get the subject and the from address to from my gmail account.And then i need to mark the accessed as read on gmail
Should i use gmail pop3 clint?is that any framework that i can use for accessing gmail pop3
server.

Comment: Did you know that you get +2 score if you accept an answer? Any one of these 3 will work. Pick one.

Answer (score 14):

I would just use the [PHP imap functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php) and do something like this:

```
<?php
    $mailbox = imap_open("{imap.googlemail.com:993/ssl}INBOX", "USERNAME@googlemail.com", "PASSWORD");
    $mail = imap_search($mailbox, "ALL");
    $mail_headers = imap_headerinfo($mailbox, $mail[0]);
    $subject = $mail_headers->subject;
    $from = $mail_headers->fromaddress;
    imap_setflag_full($mailbox, $mail[0], "\\Seen \\Flagged");
    imap_close($mailbox);
?>
```

This connects to imap.googlemail.com (googlemail's imap server), sets $subject to the subject of the first message and $from to the from address of the first message. Then, it marks this message as read. (It's untested, but it *should* work :S)

Answer (score 4):

This works for me.

```
<?php

$yourEmail = "you@gmail.com";
$yourEmailPassword = "your password";

$mailbox = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}INBOX", $yourEmail, $yourEmailPassword);
$mail = imap_search($mailbox, "ALL");
$mail_headers = imap_headerinfo($mailbox, $mail[0]);
$subject = $mail_headers->subject;
$from = $mail_headers->fromaddress;
imap_setflag_full($mailbox, $mail[0], "\\Seen \\Flagged");
imap_close($mailbox);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [IMAP](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php) from PHP.

```
<?php
$mbox = imap_open("{imap.example.org:143}", "username", "password")
     or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

$status = imap_setflag_full($mbox, "2,5", "\\Seen \\Flagged");

echo gettype($status) . "\n";
echo $status . "\n";

imap_close($mbox);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another nice IMAP example is available at http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap

Answer (score 1):

Zend Framework has the Zend_Mail API for reading mail as well. It makes it easy to switch protocols if need be (POP3, IMAP, Mbox, and Maildir). Only the IMAP and Maildir storage classes support setting flags at this time.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html

Read messages example from the Zend Framework docs:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Pop3(array('host'     => 'localhost',
                                         'user'     => 'test',
                                         'password' => 'test'));

echo $mail->countMessages() . " messages found\n";
foreach ($mail as $message) {
    echo "Mail from '{$message->from}': {$message->subject}\n";
}
```